# Typecasting Char to a structure type

Tags: c, casting

I was working on a prob and as a part of it came across problem of the follwing type...

For the foll code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct sample
{
  int a;
  char b;
}sample;

int main()
{
  char *buf;

  buf = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof(sample));

  buf = ((sample *) buf);
  buf->a = 10;
  buf->b = 'm';
  printf("%d\n",(buf)->a);
  printf("%c\n",(buf)->b);

  return 0;
}
```

Compile time error was:

example.c:16: error: request for member `a' in something not a structure or union
example.c:17: error: request for member`b' in something not a structure or union

Is this because I cannot typecast a lower data type to higher type..??

I tried using Calloc in place of malloc so that a contiguos block can be allocated but to no avail..

Help me find the logical flaw in this conversion...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Fixed formatting for you, use 4 spaces of indent for code.

Answer (score 4):

Yopu should change

```
char *buf;    
buf = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof(sample));
```

to

```
sample *buf;    
buf = (sample *)malloc(sizeof(sample));
```

because declaring buf as char * prevents the compiler from understand your intention (to point to a sample structure).

Answer (score 2):

The line `buf = ((sample *) buf);` doesn't do anything. The variable `buf` still is of type `char*`.

```
sample* sample = (sample*)malloc(sizeof(sample));
sample->a = 10;
sample->b = 'm';
printf("%d\n",(sample)->a);
printf("%c\n",(sample)->b);
```

Is more like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

the type of buf does not change with the cast, you need to add an extra variable:

```
char* buf;
sample* s;

buf = malloc(sizeof(sample));
sample = (sample*)buf;
```

the `sizeof(char)` is completely superfluous by the way, it is 1 by definition.

Answer (score 0):

`buf`'s type is still `char *`. Casting does not change the type of the receiving variable. The casts you are doing here is essentially pointless - the value of a pointer is not influenced by what it points to. Memory is memory.

To fix this, change the type of `buf` to `sample *`.

To fix it even further, remove the cast from `malloc` and the "recasting" of `buf` after it.